# How to return the key with the largest value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, max

Say I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
dct = {'key1':('Hello, Python!', 1), 'key2':(10, 2), 'aa':(9.9, 3)}
```

How do I return the key which has the highest 2nd value, ie. the highest 2nd value between 1, 2 and 3 is 3, therefore the returned key is:

```
'aa'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max`.

```
max(dct.items(),key=lambda x:x[1][1])
# ('aa', (9.9, 3))
```

If you just want `'aa'`

```
max(dct.items(),key=lambda x:x[1][1])[0]
# 'aa'
```

Comment: Thanks. What does `x:x[1][1]` here mean?

Comment: @Leockl `dct.items()` returns (key,value) in yourcase that would be (key,t(val0,val1)) to get the 2nd value in the value tuple you should index `(key,t(val0,val1))[1][1]--->val1`. If it helped please mark this as answer and upvote. ;)

Comment: Got you! Many thanks. Feel so dumb for asking that now.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the dictionary by values (`item[1]` when you parse `dct.items()`), and especially by the second element of these values (`item[1][1]`).
Then your max is the first element of the sorted list.

```
ordered_keys = [k for k, v in sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][1], reverse=True)]
best = ordered_keys[0]
```

Comment: `item[1]` is the second element of the pair (key, value) in the dictionary (then it's the value). `item[1][1]` is the second element of this value, then resp. 1, 2, 3 in your example.